# C# Combine Two Mysql Column Name as one

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

In C# Asp.net am trying to combine two columns data as one and show in the drop down but when am not able to do that as `DD_TName1.DataTextField = "FirstName" + ' ' + "LastName";` the problem is hear and the consol error is

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'FirstName LastName'.

according to Console error the column names to be converted to string as the FirstName  LastName are read by db as one column name

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from euser_teacher WHERE SchoolId='" + Schoolid + "' and StaffType='Teaching' and IsDeleted='0'  order by FirstName     ASC"))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DD_TName1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                DD_TName1.DataTextField = "FirstName" + ' ' + "LastName";
                DD_TName1.DataValueField = "TeacherId";
                DD_TName1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about modifying the SELECT-Statement?

mySQL:

```
SELECT TeacherId, Concat(FirstName, ' ',LastName) AS FirstLast from euser_teacher WHERE
```

C#

```
DD_TName1.DataTextField = "FirstLast";
DD_TName1.DataValueField = "TeacherId";
```

Comment: u should have mentioned it clearly agree  #Rakin modified ur code but he was more specific :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your sql from select * to select FirstName, LastName(fieldname as required)